# Muliple Rows in Single Column Sql Server 2008 Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

My Table Structure And Data Looks like this

```
JobNo  JobStage         JobStatus

00645  Documentation    Copy Doc Recvd in mail / Courier 
00645  Documentation    Waiting for Arrival of shipment 
00645  Documentation    Online filing 
00645  Documentation    DutyIntimation
00645  Documentation    Collection of DO
00645  Documentation    DutyPaid
00645  Documentation    Examination in Process
00645  Documentation    OOC Taken
00645  Documentation    Delivered
00645  Shed             Goods Receiced 
00645  Shed             Verification 
00645  Shed             Online filing 
00645  Delivery         Deliverd
```

And i want Like this

```
JobNo JobStage      JobStatus

00645 Documentation Copy Doc Recvd in mail / Courier
                    Waiting for Arrival of shipment 
                    Online filing
                    DutyIntimation
                    Collection of DO
                    DutyPaid
                    Examination in Process
                    OOC Taken
                    Deleiverd
00645  Shed         Goods Received
                    Verification
                    Online Filling
00645  Deleivery    Delivered

To display single row with multiple rows like above 
Kindly advise me 
Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: This kind of processing is usually better to be done on the client that receives the data.

Comment: am using asp.net kindly tell me what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asp.net GridView` control to display mentioned data.

All you need to do is group your data.
You can use ado.net or Entity framework to get data from your database.  and bind it with your grid.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    runat = "server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="OnDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobNo" HeaderText="Job number" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobStage" HeaderText="Job stage" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobStatus" HeaderText="Job status" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT JobNo, JobStage, JobStatus FROM YourTABLE GROUP BY JobNo, JobStage, JobStatus");

            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

You have to write some logic in `OnDataBound()` event of GridView. The OnDataBound event of the GridView is executed after the GridView is populated with records. The reverse loop is executed over the GridView Rows and then the common Cells are identified and merged into single cell.

```
protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
    GridViewRow previousRow = GridView1.Rows[i - 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
    {
        if (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
        {
            if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
            {
                if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                {
                    previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope this will helps you.